# ValidationResults on TryValidateObject is null

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I am trying to get my head around data annotations.

Here's my class:

```
public class Video
{
    [Required]
    public string Title {get; set; }

    public List<ValidationResult> ValidationResults { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(this, null, null);
        return Validator.TryValidateObject(this, context, this.ValidationResults);
    }
}
```

If I create an object of type Video without setting a Title, IsValid returns false (correct!), but the ValidationResults of the objects are null. Aren't they suppose to contain a ValidationResult with an error message saying that video is required or something?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, the `validateAllProperties` parameter needs to be set as `true`. e.g.

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, ValidationResults, true)
```